# Loading static properties file class

Tags: java, unit-testing, properties, dependency-injection

Currently I am using a singleton class to read and load the propertied file. I get an instance of this in any class where I want to use a property value.

Would not it be better to use a static class instead which can be loaded once (when server started or something .. ) instead of using a singleton ? Why and why not  ?

Moreover how can we load a static class OnServerStart or when war gets deployed.

PS: Project is  web application

Comment: Depending on how the properties are used, why not use Atomic or volatile variable that can be shared application wide?

Comment: In a web application you can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Comment: ServletContextListener to load properties file ? How ?

Comment: You specify a class that loads the properties file. There is ample documentation, the ServletContextListener will be defined in your web.xml. Search examples, it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton is better for dependency injection and unit testing than statics.

You may inject an instance of singleton class or a Mock of that type to any other class under test.

```
public class PropertiesHolder {
   private static final PropertiesHolder INSTANCE = new PropertiesHolder();

   private final Properties props;

   private PropertiesHolder() {
       props = load();
   }

   public static PropertiesHolder getInstance() {
       return INSTANCE;
   }

   public String getProperty(String key) {
       return props.getProperty(key);
   }

   private Properties load() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Then you may mock PropertiesHolder in your test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest { 

   @Mock private PropertiesHolder holder;

   @Test
   public void testSomething() {
      SomeService service = new SomeService(holder);

      when(holder.getProperty("foo")).thenReturn("bar");

      String result = service.doSomething(); 

      assertEquals(...)
   }

}
```

For production code you may use:

```
new SomeService(PropertiesHolder.getInstance());
```

Or even better, use DI framework, e.g. Spring, for wiring a beans. PropertiesHolder would be a generic bean with factory method `getInstance()` and the scope 'singleton'.

If you're using Spring in your web application I'd suggest using with it's [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

If you don't want to use Spring for that and need to do some actions (e.g. loading property file) on servlet when webapp is started then use [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) as Bhesh Gurung has suggested.

Comment: I am not sure if I got it completely or at all for that matter. I am not into testing world ... so hardly understand any terms that you have used. My properties file is simply a list of few properties required to be used across web application

Comment: Then use a singleton. It would be easier to refactor later.

Comment: But still curious to learn what you were saying in the answer .. if you don't mind elaborating a bit on it